# combine two record become one with unique id for large data

Tags: mysql, record

I have table `PNS` for employee with `NIP as primary key`
table `JADWAL` for schedule of employee with `idjadwal as primary`
table `PRESTEMP` data from finger print machine that the format is 1 row for 1 time capture.

I want to convert table `PRESTEMP` where there are stored data from finger print machine into table `PRESENSI` that the format is one row for `timein` and `timeout` indexed with column `NIP`.

For example Table Name : PRESTEMP

```
NIP                  DATETIME
196611292006041002   2019-01-01 07:01:58
196611292006041002   2019-01-01 07:10:58
196611292006041002   2019-01-01 14:02:58
196611292006041002   2019-01-01 14:09:36
```

These four record I want to combine into one record depend on table JADWAL and table PNS, only the earlier time and the latest time.

to become table name : PRESENSI, depends on table PNS and table JADWAL

```
NIP                   DATE          TIMEIN   TIMEOUT
196611292006041002    2019-01-01    07:01:58  14:09:36
```

I used mysql 5.5 on UBUNTU 14.04

```
create temporary table impresensi (index tgl (tgl),index nip (nip), index timein (timein), index timeout (timeout), index shift (shift)) select jadwal.tgl jadwal.nip,jamkerja.timein,jamkerja.timeinpre,jamkerja.timeinpost, jamkerja.timeout, jamkerja.timeoutpre,jamkerja.timeoutpost,jamkerja.shift from (jadwal join jamkerja on((jadwal.idjamkerja = jamkerja.id))) where (tgl between dtanggal1 and dtanggal2);

create temporary table impresensi1 (index nip (comnip),index timein (timein), index timeout (timeout), index tanggal (tanggal), index shift (shift)) select sql_no_cache l.id,comnip,min(comtime) timein,'00:00:00' timeout, comdate tanggal,shift,comMesinID,comdatetime diffin,null diffout from prestemp l inner join impresensi r on l.comnip = nip and comdate = r.tgl where (comtime between timeinpre and timeinpost) and (comdate between dtanggal1 and dtanggal2) group by comnip, comdate;

create temporary table impresensi2 (index nip (comnip),index timein (timein), index timeout (timeout), index tanggal(tanggal), index shift (shift)) select sql_no_cache l.id,comnip,'00:00:00' timein,max(comtime) timeout, comdate tanggal,shift,comMesinID,null diffin, comdatetime diffout from prestemp l inner join impresensi r on l.comnip = r.nip and comdate = r.tgl where (comtime between timeoutpre and timeoutpost) and (comdate between dtanggal1 and dtanggal2) group by comnip,comdate;

update impresensi2 set tanggal = date_add(tanggal,interval -1 day) where shift = 1;
```

YES, I solved what I want, but I got a long time to process `10.875 employees (on table PNS)` and every employee has 30 days of work schedule, it’s mean `326.250 records (on table JADWAL)`, and every employee could be have 2 or more record from finger print machine, at least `652.500 records` for a month (on table PRESTEMP) and I got `1.356 seconds` to process all of it.

Is there is something wrong with my logical program ? please Help me to reduce time processing.